# Verwendung eines gemeinsamen Letters für "u" und "v" in alten Drucken

Tags: typography, blackletter

Diese Frage ist motiviert durch [Unknown word "Beuelch" on title page of 16th century German hymnal](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/76002/34192).

Im [Speyerer Gesangbuch von 1599](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alte_Catholische_Geistliche_Kirchengesen/q-D-_FGku98C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA29-IA1&printsec=frontcover) werden die Buchstaben "u" und "v" im Druck nicht unterschieden. Mich hat aber überrascht, dass zwei verschiedene Frakturbuchstaben verwendet werden, um "u / v" darzustellen.

1. Am Wortanfang wird der Letter [image] verwendet, der wie ein Fraktur-v aussieht.
2. Im Inneren eines Wortes wird der Letter [image] verwendet, der wie ein Fraktur-u aussieht.

Hier einige Beispiele:

- [image]
- [image]

Meine Fragen:

War die Verwendung von zwei verschiedenen Lettern für "u / v" in Abhängigkeit von der Position innerhalb eines Wortes üblich oder ist das eine Besonderheit des vorliegenden Drucks?

Seit wann werden "u" und "v" im Sinne einer phonetischen Diffenzierung konsequent durch Verwendung von individuellen Lettern unterschieden?

**Update:**

Die Frage nach der Verwendung der Frakturletter "u" und  "v" stellt sich erst mit der Erfindung des Buchdrucks durch Gutenberg Mitte des 15. Jahrhunderts. In der (lateinischen) Gutenberg-Bibel (s. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Gutenberg_Bible_B42_Genesis.JPG)) werden die Frakturletter "u" und "v" phonetisch korrekt verwendet:
[image]
Erst nach Luthers Bibelübersetzung gab es Druckerzeugnisse in deutscher Sprache, und es tritt damit auch die positionsabhängige Verwendung von Lettern für "u / v" auf. S. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimarer_Lutherbibel_von_1534#/media/Datei:Luther_1534,_Genesis_I.jpg):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tatsächlich hat das Phänomen nichts (bzw. nur wenig) direkt mit der Frakturschrift  zu tun.

Lange Zeit waren "v" und "u" im Deutschen (und anderen europäischen Schriftsprachen, z.B. Latein) einfach derselbe Buchstabe - Die Unterscheidung findet erst sehr spät statt und dein Beispiel kommt aus einer (langen) Übergangsperiode etwa ab dem 15. - 17. Jahrhundert, wo man sich mangels einer richtigen Standardisierung noch nicht so recht entscheiden konnte. Lange wurde ein "v" am Wortanfang und ein "u" im Wort für denselben Buchstaben verwendet (und das "w" als "Doppel-v" oder "Doppel-u" (siehe dazu auch den Namen des Buchstabens im Englischen)).

Comment: Hat irgendjemand mal diese Unterscheidung – v am Wortanfang und u in der Mitte – als Regel oder Empfehlung formuliert, oder zumindest den Sinn begründet?

Comment: @ccprog Ich glaube nicht, oder wenn, dann glaube ich nicht, dass etwas davon erhalten wäre. Rechtschreibung war damals eine "Verlagsnorm" (Verlage und Druckereien waren lange Zeit dasselbe und der Drucker gleichzeitig Herausgeber und Lektor in Personalunion) und auch eine Art "Betriebsgeheimnis" und "unique selling point".

Comment: Heißt das, dass erst ab dem 18. Jahrhundert eine phonetisch orientierte Differenzierung von "u" und "v" zu beobachten ist?

Comment: Nein, nicht direkt - Das sieht man vereinzelt schon lange vorher. Aber eben "vereinzelt und zunehmend öfter". Deutsch ist halt eine Sprache, die lange Zeit nach Lust und Laune geschrieben wurde. Und: Ob "u" und "v" tatsächlich immer "phonetisch diferenziert" sind, darüber kann man sich (außer im Anlaut) auch heute noch vortrefflich streiten.